# Visual Studio Code - Powershell - High CPU and Slow performance switching between Powershell files

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a fresh installation of Visual Studio Code 1.16.1

I have the following extensions:

- Chef Extension for Visual Studio Code 0.6.3
- Code Outline 0.0.10
- Powershell 1.4.3
- Ruby 0.15.0

I try to edit Powershell within VSCode. 
Powershell is loaded (Version 5.1)

But every time I switch between one of my open files (In the current test case, an psm1 and psd1) I see a little loading bar at the top of the Explorer sidebar, just below the Explorer text.

While that's going, I can't "Run Selection", Code Outline does not update nor do I have any form of syntax-assistance while writing code UNTIL it is done. Then all of the items you tried to do, happen all at once.

Until I switch windows, everything works as expected. The moment I switch files, it starts "loading/working" again and I have to wait about 30 seconds for it to do it's thing.

I have also tried disabling all extensions (except Powershell)  and I see nearly the same behavior. When switching tabs, the loading happens but I don't see the loading bar in the explorer sidebar described above.

I currently do not have a different machine to test this on, working on getting a second machine to rule out the computer.

I am looking into logging a bug but before I do, I wanted to check here.

Comment: This is a problem I've seen that made me go back to the ISE for PowerShell development.  Every time you close/open a project, it has to launch a new host and it doesn't cleanly close the old one.